# How to save the entire HTML source of a page being tested with Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

How can I use Cypress to save the entire HTML source of a page as a text file, as if I right-clicked on the page and selected "View Source"?

This generates a JSON object that doesn't include the HTML

```
cy.document().then((doc) => {
  cy.writeFile('pageMarkup.html', doc);
});
```

and this outputs a bunch of CSS and JavaScript, but it still doesn't include most of the actual HTML document

```
cy.get('html:root').eq(0).invoke('text').then((doc) => {
  cy.writeFile('pageMarkup.html', doc);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I've gotten close enough by using the following:

```
cy.get('html:root').eq(0).invoke('prop', 'innerHTML').then((doc: any) => {
  cy.writeFile('pageMarkup.html', doc);
});
```

The file that it creates has additional CSS and an embedded Cypress script tag that are different from what I would see as an actual user, but it does contain the HTML.  If anyone has an idea on how to refine this to more closely match an end-user's "View Source" from the context menu, please post.

Comment: This will omit the `html` tag, change to `outerHTML` to include it.